# Unable to enable Powershell Remoting

Tags: powershell, remoting

When i try to enable PSRemoting my machine yells at me, telling me that there's an issue with Set-WSManQuickConfig. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it. Ideas?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-PSRemoting

WinRM Quick Configuration
Running command "Set-WSManQuickConfig" to enable this machine for remote management through WinRM service.
 This includes:
    1. Starting or restarting (if already started) the WinRM service
    2. Setting the WinRM service type to auto start
    3. Creating a listener to accept requests on any IP address
    4. Enabling firewall exception for WS-Management traffic (for http only).

Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
Set-WSManQuickConfig : The WinRM client cannot complete the operation within the time specified. Check if the machine n
ame is valid and is reachable over the network and firewall exception for Windows Remote Management service is enabled.

At line:50 char:33
+             Set-WSManQuickConfig <<<<  -force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

Comment: What OS is this? Windows XP, Vista, Win7? Is this system in a domain?

Comment: http://www.nivot.org/nivot2/post/2009/10/30/PowerShell20EnablingRemotingWithVirtualXPModeOnWindows7.aspx

Comment: Windows 7, Windows Powershell as Administrator. 
The system is on a domain.

Comment: @David Brabant Thanks for the link but I'm afraid it didn't work - I'm not running in XP mode and I already have "Classic" mode active.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trouble shooting guide to fixing this problem, it covers:

- Is your machine connected to a domain or work group?
- Are you logged in as a local Administrator?
- Was PowerShell launched as 'Administrator'?
- Is your password blank?
- Are you trying to connect to a SharePoint farm?
- Is your Server hosted/managed by a Hosting company?
- Are you using VirtualBox?
- Are you running Windows XP?
- Are you running the command on a computer where the language is not
  set to English?

[https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied/568228#568228)